# Explicitly instantiating a C# class that uses DI - why doesn't it work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using ASP.NET Core Web API.  I am having a hard time wrapping my head around instantiating a *non-controller* class that uses DI.   There are a multitude of SO articles related to this, but none that have answered my question (as far as I can understand).  These are the most popular and relevant:

[Net Core Dependency Injection for Non-Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41614194/net-core-dependency-injection-for-non-controller)

[Dependency Injection without a Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50293476/dependency-injection-without-a-controller)

[ASP.NET 5 Non-Controller DI injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34618379/asp-net-5-non-controller-di-injection)

My use case (a contrived example):

I have a class `SpeechWriter` that has a dependency on `IRandomTextService`:

```
public class SpeechWriter
{
    private readonly IRandomTextService _textService;
    
    // Constructor with Text Service DI
    public SpeechWriter(IRandomTextService textService)
    {
        _textService = textService;
    }

    public string WriteSpeech()
    {
        var speech = _textService.GetText(new Random().Next(5,50));

        return speech;
    }
}
```

`IRandomTextService` interface:

```
public interface IRandomTextService
{
    public string GetText(int wordCount);
}
```

and the implementation:

```
public class RandomTextService : IRandomTextService
{
    public string GetText(int wordCount)
    {
        return Lorem.Words(wordCount);
    }
}
```

`IRandomTextService` is registered as a service in `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();

    services.AddScoped<IRandomTextService, RandomTextService>();
}
```

In my controller action, if I want to instantiate a `SpeechWriter` like this:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var speech = new SpeechWriter();

    return Ok(speech.WriteSpeech());
}
```

I can't do it because an argument (the injected service) is expected.

[image: SpeechWriter requires the RandomTextService as a parameter]

The only way I can seem to get DI to inject `RandomTextService` in `SpeechWriter` is if `SpeechWriter` itself is a service and injected in the controller:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();

    services.AddScoped<IRandomTextService, RandomTextService>();
    services.AddScoped<SpeechWriter>();
}
```

```
public class EchoController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly SpeechWriter _speechWriter;
    
    public EchoController(SpeechWriter speechWriter)
    {
        _speechWriter = speechWriter;
    }
    
    
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return Ok(_speechWriter.WriteSpeech());
    }
}
```

Is there any way to get `RandomTextService` injected when `SpeechWriter` is instantiated as in my first example, like this?

```
var speech = new SpeechWriter();
```

If not, what is it about DI that I'm missing?  My actual application is more complex than this and I would effectively have to create a chain of DI and services all the way back up to the controller.   I could use the `ServiceProvider` "anti-pattern", but I prefer not to do that because I'd be passing `ServiceProvider` all over the place.

Please help educate me!

Thanks.

Comment: "*I would effectively have to create a chain of DI and services all the way back up to the controller*" -- I don't follow this point. You inject `SpeechWriter` into whatever class needs it. How does that create a chain back to the controller?

Comment: What is wrong with injecting the `SpeechWriter`? Actually the controller has a dependency on it, so it should be injected and not instantiated manually. If you see a `new YourType` in your code it looks suspicious

Comment: _"a chain of DI and services all the way"_ is exactly the goal. Either you do DI or you don't.

Comment: The mistake here is that you are `new`ing up `SpeechWriter` instead of injecting it.

Comment: The point of DI is making dependencies explicit  by injecting them -- explicitly. A DI *framework* is just a way of doing this by orchestrating things at the top level. When you want to create a new `SpeechWriter`, you must also have an `IRandomTextService` at hand. How you get it is up to you, but you cannot leave it out and pretend `SpeechWriter` works on its own -- that's a feature, not a bug. Note that a higher-level class can also have a class take a dependency on a factory (e.g. `Func<ISpeechWriter>`) to abstract over the creation without taking a hard dependency on the framework.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 not my actual code!

Comment: Why not add the missing parameter to Index?

Comment: Rule of thumb: When using DI *never* write "new"

Comment: @pinkfloydx33: what bug? Note that the empty `Random`-constructor behaviour has changed with .net core. It no longer relies on the system time. The seed will always be random.

Comment: All these comments are extremely helpful -- I am being educated!  Based on these comments, it seems I'm not strictly adhering to DI because I'm new-ing up a class that uses DI.   If I need to do that, then it's a sign that I need to do some refactoring to implement DI correctly.

Comment: @TimSchmelter wow it appears you are correct. I retract my comment. Also interesting there's now a [`Random.Shared` property](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/ee32ee2240f5771f9cf162695d110c2adccc5107/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Random.cs#L51)

Comment: I'm also struggling with grasping the "practicalities" of DI, as the author was. Does that mean, that if I have registered service e.g. doing logging, db-connection or random text, then I will also need to register all consumers of these services....and in turn all consumers of these?